Android 11 - Help neded to use PackageManager to silent install APK as DeviceOwner
I  My app is launcher and a Device Admin/Owner app.
Currently for demo i am trying to download the wireguard APK and install it silently with this code below. However adb logcat shows errors
12-18 11:33:12.792 9785 9825 D APKDownload: APK downloaded to /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myapplication/files/Download/wireguard.apk
12-18 11:33:13.701 9785 9825 E APKInstallError: at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.installAPK(MainActivity.kt:254)
12-18 11:33:13.701 9785 9825 E APKInstallError: at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.downloadAndInstallAPK$lambda$3(MainActivity.kt:209)
12-18 11:33:13.701 9785 9825 E APKInstallError: at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$7V-msg0KHXrPMcl9_lfTIQBMiZE(Unknown Source:0)
12-18 11:33:13.701 9785 9825 E APKInstallError: at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
and the toast that displays on the screen shows
(write failed: ebadf (bad file descriptor) Can any one help me identity why I am getting this error.
currently i need this to work on android 11
  private fun downloadAndInstallAPK(urlString: String) {
        Thread {
            try {
                val url = URL(urlString)
                val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                connection.requestMethod = "GET"
                connection.connect()

                val inputStream = connection.inputStream
                val file = File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "wireguard.apk")
                val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)

                val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
                var length: Int
                while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { length = it } != -1) {
                    fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length)
                }

                fileOutputStream.close()
                inputStream.close()

                Log.d("APKDownload", "APK downloaded to ${file.absolutePath}")
                // Install the APK
                installAPK(file)

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                runOnUiThread {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error downloading APK: ${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        }.start()
    }

    private fun installAPK(file: File) {

        val packageInstaller = packageManager.packageInstaller

        try {
            val params = PackageInstaller.SessionParams(PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL)
            val sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params)

            // Open the session
            val session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId)

            // Open the output stream to write the APK into the session
            val out = session.openWrite("wireguard.apk", 0, -1)

            // Copy APK data from input to session
            val inputStream = FileInputStream(file)
            val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
            var length: Int
            while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { length = it } != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, length)
            }
            inputStream.close()
            out.close()

            // Prepare the IntentSender for installation completion callback
            val intent = Intent("com.example.myapplication.ACTION_INSTALL_COMPLETE")
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this,
                0,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )

            // Commit the session
            session.fsync(out)
            session.commit(pendingIntent.intentSender)

            // Inform user
            runOnUiThread {
                Toast.makeText(this, "App installation initiated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("APKInstallError", "Error during APK installation: ${e.message}", e)
            runOnUiThread {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error installing APK: ${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }


Android Manifest.
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <!-- Add permission for accessing the MAC address and SN -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DEVICE_ADMINS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_USERS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.wireguard.android" />
        <!-- Add other packages you want to query here -->
    </queries>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <!-- Main Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Boot Receiver -->
        <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name=".DeviceAdminReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"
            android:exported="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.myapplication.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

    </application>

</manifest>

